# dataweave2.0 transformation in mule 4 based on conditions

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-esb, mulesoft, mule4

I've to write some transformation and calculation based on condition like count of cash/dd/cheque receipt and sum of cash/dd/cheque in the summary array. I've defined my input array and based on that i'm expecting the output that I've defined. Help me to complete the dataweave for that.\

Code:

```
    %dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    {
      receipt: payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
      receiptId: payload01.receiptId,
      amountCollected: payload01.amountCollected,
      paymentMode: payload01.paymentMode,
    },
      summary: {
      TotalamountCollected: payload.*amountCollected reduce ((val, acc=0) -> acc + val)
      }
   }
```

input:

```
[{
    "receiptId": 11000134453,
    "amountCollected": 11,
    "paymentMode": "Cash"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1105444723,
    "amountCollected": 12,
    "paymentMode": "Cheque"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1143434763,
    "amountCollected": 13,
    "paymentMode": "DD"
},{
    "receiptId": 11000134457,
    "amountCollected": 14,
    "paymentMode": "Cash"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1105444728,
    "amountCollected": 15,
    "paymentMode": "Cheque"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1143434769,
    "amountCollected": 16,
    "paymentMode": "DD"
}]
```

output:

```
{
    "summary": {
        "TotalamountCollected": 81,
        "cashRecepit": 2,
        "cashRecepitAmount": 25,
        "chequeRecepit": 2,
        "chequeRecepitAmount": 27,
        "ddRecepit": 2,
        "ddRecepitAmount": 29
    },
    "receipt": [{
        "receiptId": 11000134453,
        "amountCollected": 11,
        "paymentMode": "Cash"
    }, {
        "receiptId": 1105444723,
        "amountCollected": 12,
        "paymentMode": "Cheque"
    }, {
        "receiptId": 1143434763,
        "amountCollected": 13,
        "paymentMode": "DD"
    },{
        "receiptId": 11000134457,
        "amountCollected": 14,
        "paymentMode": "Cash"
    }, {
        "receiptId": 1105444728,
        "amountCollected": 15,
        "paymentMode": "Cheque"
    }, {
        "receiptId": 1143434769,
        "amountCollected": 16,
        "paymentMode": "DD"
    }]
}
```

Help me to complete the dataweave for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that involves one iteration over the input.  I'm curious if anyone has any cleaner solutions.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var inputVar =
    [{
        "receiptId": 11000134453,
        "amountCollected": 11,
        "paymentMode": "Cash"
    }, {
        "receiptId": 1105444723,
        "amountCollected": 12,
        "paymentMode": "Cheque"
    }, {
        "receiptId": 1143434763,
        "amountCollected": 13,
        "paymentMode": "DD"
    },{
        "receiptId": 11000134457,
        "amountCollected": 14,
        "paymentMode": "Cash"
    }, {
        "receiptId": 1105444728,
        "amountCollected": 15,
        "paymentMode": "Cheque"
    }, {
        "receiptId": 1143434769,
        "amountCollected": 16,
        "paymentMode": "DD"
    }]

var init =     
    {
        "TotalamountCollected": 0,
        "cashRecepit": 0,
        "cashRecepitAmount": 0,
        "chequeRecepit": 0,
        "chequeRecepitAmount": 0,
        "ddRecepit": 0,
        "ddRecepitAmount": 0
    }

fun calcModeAmmount(acc, isTargetedMode, addend) = acc + if(isTargetedMode) addend else 0

fun summary() = inputVar reduce(item, acc=init) ->
    {
        "TotalamountCollected": acc.TotalamountCollected + item.amountCollected,
        "cashRecepit": calcModeAmmount(acc.cashRecepit, item.paymentMode == "Cash", 1),
        "cashRecepitAmount": calcModeAmmount(acc.cashRecepitAmount, item.paymentMode == "Cash", item.amountCollected),
        "chequeRecepit": calcModeAmmount(acc.chequeRecepit, item.paymentMode == "Cheque", 1),
        "chequeRecepitAmount": calcModeAmmount(acc.chequeRecepitAmount, item.paymentMode == "Cheque", item.amountCollected),
        "ddRecepit": calcModeAmmount(acc.ddRecepit, item.paymentMode == "DD", 1),
        "ddRecepitAmount": calcModeAmmount(acc.ddRecepitAmount, item.paymentMode == "DD", item.amountCollected)
    }
---
{
    summary:summary(),
    receipt:inputVar
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are number of ways you can get it done.

1) Here's a flexible, process but not space efficient way you can get it done:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw

var data = [{
    "receiptId": 11000134453,
    "amountCollected": 11,
    "paymentMode": "Cash"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1105444723,
    "amountCollected": 12,
    "paymentMode": "Cheque"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1143434763,
    "amountCollected": 13,
    "paymentMode": "DD"
},{
    "receiptId": 11000134457,
    "amountCollected": 14,
    "paymentMode": "Cash"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1105444728,
    "amountCollected": 15,
    "paymentMode": "Cheque"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1143434769,
    "amountCollected": 16,
    "paymentMode": "DD"
}]

---
do {
    var byPaymentMode = data groupBy $.paymentMode
    ---
    {
        summary: (byPaymentMode mapObject {
            (lower($$) ++ "Receipt"): sizeOf($),
            (lower($$) ++ "ReceiptAmount"): sum($.*amountCollected)
        }),
        receipt: data
    }   
}
```

2) Here's a not flexible, space but not process efficient way to get it done using the build-in `dw::core::Arrays` module.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw

var data = [{
    "receiptId": 11000134453,
    "amountCollected": 11,
    "paymentMode": "Cash"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1105444723,
    "amountCollected": 12,
    "paymentMode": "Cheque"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1143434763,
    "amountCollected": 13,
    "paymentMode": "DD"
},{
    "receiptId": 11000134457,
    "amountCollected": 14,
    "paymentMode": "Cash"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1105444728,
    "amountCollected": 15,
    "paymentMode": "Cheque"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1143434769,
    "amountCollected": 16,
    "paymentMode": "DD"
}]

---
{
    summary: {
        TotalAmountCollected: data dw::core::Arrays::sumBy (e) -> e.amountCollected,
        cashReceipt: data dw::core::Arrays::countBy (e) -> e.paymentMode == "Cash",
        cashReceiptAmount: data dw::core::Arrays::sumBy (e) -> if (e.paymentMode == "Cash") e.amountCollected else 0,
        checkReceipt: data dw::core::Arrays::countBy (e) -> e.paymentMode == "Cheque",
        checkReceiptAmount: data dw::core::Arrays::sumBy (e) -> if (e.paymentMode == "Cheque") e.amountCollected else 0,
        ddReceipt: data dw::core::Arrays::countBy (e) -> e.paymentMode == "DD",
        ddReceiptAmount: data dw::core::Arrays::sumBy (e) -> if (e.paymentMode == "DD") e.amountCollected else 0
    },
    receipt: data
}
```

This last solution can also be made flexible quite easily so you do not hard-code the `paymentMode`s.

Pick the one you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer...Hope it helps

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
var inputJsonArr=[{
    "receiptId": 11000134453,
    "amountCollected": 11,
    "paymentMode": "Cash"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1105444723,
    "amountCollected": 12,
    "paymentMode": "Cheque"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1143434763,
    "amountCollected": 13,
    "paymentMode": "DD"
},{
    "receiptId": 11000134457,
    "amountCollected": 14,
    "paymentMode": "Cash"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1105444728,
    "amountCollected": 15,
    "paymentMode": "Cheque"
}, {
    "receiptId": 1143434769,
    "amountCollected": 16,
    "paymentMode": "DD"
}]
---
{
summary:{
'TotalamountCollected':inputJsonArr sumBy $.amountCollected,
'cashRecepit':inputJsonArr countBy (($.paymentMode) == 'Cash'),
'cashRecepitAmount':((inputJsonArr filter  (value, index) -> ((value.paymentMode)== 'Cash'))sumBy $.amountCollected),
'chequeRecepit':inputJsonArr countBy (($.paymentMode) == 'Cheque'),
'chequeRecepitAmount':((inputJsonArr filter  (value, index) -> ((value.paymentMode)== 'Cheque'))sumBy $.amountCollected),
'ddRecepit':inputJsonArr countBy (($.paymentMode) == 'DD'),
'ddRecepitAmount':((inputJsonArr filter  (value, index) -> ((value.paymentMode)== 'DD'))sumBy $.amountCollected)
},
'receipt':inputJsonArr
}
```